# Prove/disprove: $\exists N\in\mathbb{R}:\forall x\in\mathbb{R}:(x>N\implies f(x)=0)$

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a function such that $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)g(x)}{x}=0$ for every $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$.
>   Prove/disprove: $\exists N\in\mathbb{R}:\forall x\in\mathbb{R}:(x>N\implies f(x)=0)$

Attempt

Suppose $\forall N\in\mathbb{R}:\exists x\in\mathbb{R}:(x>N\wedge (f(x)>0\quad\vee\quad f(x)<0))$
Let $x_n$ be a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n=\infty$ and $f(x_n)\neq 0$
Define $g(x)=x$ and we get a contradiction.

*Comment*
I'm not sure about this proof. It seems flawed in terms of how different $f(x_n)$ is from $0$. What guarantees that $f(x_n)$ never converges to $0$?

Comment: The statement is for every g.  I do not think you can take a specific g and state that it is a contradiction.

Answer (score 5):

Nothing.

But try
$$g(x)=\begin{cases}\frac x{f(x)}&f(x)\ne 0\\42&f(x)=0\end{cases} $$